# How to control chrome desktop notifications

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension, which fires desktop notifications to users, once a day or once a week based on the settings i have given. So in order to show the notification what I did is i saved the time in milliseconds and calling setInterval.

```
window.setInterval(readFromDB, parseInt(localStorage['Timer']));
```

readFromDB function reads from localdatabase and shows one desktop notification to the user.
Since the Timer value I stored is 86400000 i expect the function invoked again after one day and the notification shows up.

But the problem here, what if the browser is completely closed or machine is not turned OFF. If the user opens his machine after more than one day, may extension is no longer working and there are no notifications firing up.

Can someone help me where am doing wrong or is there any better solution i can depend on?

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code? In the `background` file? If so, the user will have to customize this.

> Click the wrench icon  in the browser toolbar. Select Settings.
>   Show advanced settings. In "Background Apps" section, select
>   `"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"`
>   checkbox.

Comment: yes this code is background.js and also the option you mentioned is checked.

Comment: @Srikanth The user doesn't switch his machine off anywhere in this scenario, does he?

Comment: Am thinking what happens if the user turns off his machine for 2days (say over the weekend). Does that break my code?

Comment: This options is not available on Mac OS. Does it means it allows background apps by default?

Comment: @Srikanth There's no way for it to work then. There *may* be a way with NPAPI, but I don't know about that. I think it means that it isn't there at all. Have you updated?

Comment: From the Chrome [Help center] (http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1184722), its mentioned that "This is only applicable to Google Chrome browser on Windows and Linux.". I checked on Mac and the option is not available as they said. So am not clear what is the default behavior on Mac.

Comment: @Srikanth Well, there's your answer. Your extension won't work as expected on OSX.